# UnicodeError decoding data sent via UART between Raspberry Pi Pico and ESP8266

Tags: uart, decoding, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I tried to make a connection via UART between a Raspberry Pi Pico and a Wi-Fi board (ESP8266). The board sends data the Raspberry Pi Pico receives. But when decoding I get a UnicodeError without description. The data are bytes in utf-8:

```
1  from machine import UART, Pin
2  from time import sleep
3
4  uart0 = UART(0, baudrate=115200, tx=Pin(0), rx=Pin(1))
5
6  while True:
7     rxData = bytes()
8
9     while uart0.any() > 0:
10         rxData += uart0.read(1)
11
12     if len(rxData):
13         print(rxData.decode('utf-8'), end='')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in <module>
UnicodeError:
```

The data as `<type bytes>`:

```
...
b'eceiving'
b' from remote s'
b'erver\r\n"Here\'s th'
b'e rule for bargains'
b': "Do other men, f'
b'or they would do yo'
b'u."\r\n That\'s the tru'
b'e business precept.'
b'" Charles Dickens ('
b'1812-70)\r\x00\r\nclosin'
b'g connection\r\n'
...
```

Comment: The data bytes are most likely ***not*** UTF-8, otherwise you wouldn't get the error you are getting. You should print `rxData` *before* calling `.decode()` in order to see what is going on. The last data chunk to get printed will contain the invalid unicode bytes that cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try inverting the uart logic levels on the pico

```
uart0 = UART(0, baudrate=115200, bits=8, parity=None, stop=1, 
invert = UART.INV_TX | UART.INV_RX)
```